# The reflection onto a hyperplane $V\in \mathbb{R^n}$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that $ref_V(\vec{x})=2proj_V\vec{x}-\vec{x}$.

So that $ref_V(\vec{x})=\vec{x}+2(proj_V\vec{x}-\vec{x}) = 2proj_V{\vec{x}}-\vec{x}=(2proj_V\vec{x}-I)\vec{x}$

It's supposed to be that this final expression shows that the transformation is orthogonal, but I'm wondering why this is true. What about $(2proj_V\vec{x}-I)\vec{x}$ shows that $ref_V(\vec{x})$ is orthogonal?

Comment: How you deduce a particular statement depends on the definitions you're starting with. What is your definition of an orthogonal transformation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If for a transformation $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ we have that $T(\vec{e_1}),...,T(\vec{e_n})$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is to choose a different orthonormal basis.  Namely, let $v_1,\dots,v_d$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$, and let $v_{d-1},\dots,v_n$ extend the previous set to an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

Why does $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$ form an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$?

Answer (score 0):

The [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) is indeed [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix). Let $v$ be  a unit normal to the hyperplane, then the reflection matrix is $(I-2vv^T)$, and $(I-2vv^T)^T(I-2vv^T)=I$.